# Replace NA at the beginning and end of df with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na

What is the optimal package that will impute missing values in a column? I've looked at the `zoo` package that deals with time series data, and played with LOCF (`na.locf`), but that skips first `NA`...

Here is an example data frame

```
> df <- within(df, {duration[c(1,5,9)] <- NA})
> df
  duration
1       NA
2        2
3        3
4        4
5       NA
6        6
7        7
8        8
9       NA
```

Comment: What do you want imputed for the tails? `na.locf` for the end and `rev(na.locf(rev(x)))` for the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say to `na.locf` that you don't want to remove `NA`'s so it maintains the  first `NA`'s in the replacement. Then you can do another replacement saying that you want to begin from last to replace the remaining `NA`'s with the first non-`NA`elements.

```
df <-read.table(text = "duration
       NA
        2
        3
        4
       NA
        6
        7
        8
       NA", header = TRUE)

library(zoo)
df <- na.locf(df, na.rm = FALSE)
df <- na.locf(df, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)
df
  duration
1        2
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        4
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        8
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos!  Are there any other packages you'd recommend?

Comment: @Antex this is really context dependent... but you could take a look at Amelia, it is a nice package: http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia/

Comment: If you want to stay within the "Hadleyverse", `fill` from the `tidyr` package is very similar to `na.locf`